# Typescript interface fails to work

Tags: typescript, aurelia

The following code fails with an error:

> readCandidates is not a function:

Here is the code

```
export class Candidates {    
    private _dataService : ModelContracts.IDataService;    

    constructor(private tag: ModelContracts.ITag, private dataService: ModelContracts.IDataService) {
        this._value = tag;
        this._dataService = dataService;        
    }

    private _value : ModelContracts.ITag;
    public get value() : ModelContracts.ITag {
        return this._value;
    }
    public set value(v : ModelContracts.ITag) {
        this._value = v;
    }

    candidates = [];

    activate() {        
       this._dataService.readCandidates().then(candidates => this.candidates = candidates);
    }    
}

export interface IDataService {
    readCandidates(): Promise<ModelContracts.ICandidate[]>
} 

export class DataService {
    //some implementation
}
```

I'm using Aurelia bet 1.1.0 and Typescript. 
The dataService dependency gets injected but the function call fails.

Comment: There are no calls to `getCandidates` in the code you provided. The problem must be in the other part of the code.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I mean' readCanidates'...

Comment: there's no way to tell what the issue is, if dataService was a valid IDataService, it would have a function `readCandidates()`, and your application would work.

Comment: Have you tried using ``console.log(this._dataservice)`` inside of your constructor to see if the ``readCandidates()`` method even exists? The error is pretty telling, it can't find the function. I am not sure if the problem is with your interface at all. If the provided class example at the bottom ``DataService`` is what you are injecting, it is missing the ``readCandidates()`` method.

Answer (score 1):

If the context of the call is not the class (for example, because you are calling `activate` as a callback or from an event) you'll need to make sure you sort out your scope.

For example:

```
activate = () => {        
   this._dataService.readCandidates().then(candidates => this.candidates = candidates);
}
```

Although there are some better ways to do this if you want to have [a consitent approach to handling the responsibility of scope in TypeScript](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/04/typescript-scope-responsibility/). The recommendation is to handle scope off-class, as the class shouldn't know how it is going to be called.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This does not solve the problem.

Comment: @GenaVerdel please can you supply a little more detail of where the method is being called?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears I can' really use interfaces with the dependency injection in aurelia.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to use interfaces with DI in aurelia.